# How can I use my searchbar with two different values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've tried to add another value (organization.name) to my already successfully working searchbar, so that not only the list of SearchTerms from my organization.topic were filtered. But he doesnt add it..

```
    const filteredOrganizations = context.allOrganizations.filter((organization) => (organization.topic.searchTerms
        .map((term) => term.toLowerCase())
        .join(" ") ||
        organization.name)
        .includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
```

thats the relevant part of my return:

```
<TableBody>
                            {filteredOrganizations.map((organization) => (

                                <StyledTableRow key={organization.id}>
...
```

I hope you have an idea

Comment: Kindly provide more details as the given details are insufficient to understand the problem that you are facing.

Comment: What kind of details do you want to have? I want to use my Searchbar with not only the SearchTerms value

Comment: From the code snippet you have provided, it is impossible to understand what you are trying to achieve. What I understood from the question is, you have a search box and there is a list that get's updated from the search term. But you wanted to add another condition in the filter which is using `organization.name` along with other filters. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: completely right. The list is in form of a table. I could send you the full code of this page if you want, but there are mainly code and style snippets from the table

Comment: i temporarily deleted my answer to be 100% sure. so if you type a `searchText` you want this to be searched either at terms or organization name? so if an org name matches `searchText` but terms don't it should be shown?

Comment: there should only be a result, if theres a match with SearchTerms and/or the organization.name. And at this moment, it only shows matches with the SearchTerms

Comment: ok since the result is an `OR` operation, i undeleted my answer. you just have to concatenate the joined 'by empty space terms and the org name in order to create the final strng to search for the `searchText`

Comment: @JustRob please dont forget to accept answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```js
const filteredOrganizations = context.allOrganizations.filter(organization => {
        const searchTerms = organization.topic.searchTerms.map(term => term.toLowerCase()).join(" ");
        const organizationName = organization.name.toLowerCase();
        const searchString = `${searchTerms} ${organizationName}`;

        return searchString.includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `||` since you want to check also the organization name.
Just concatenate the strings

```
const filteredOrganizations = context.allOrganizations.filter(organization => 
(
  organization.topic.searchTerms
    .map(term => term.toLowerCase()).join(' ')
    + ' ' + organization.name
)
.includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchText = 'term5'; // user input

// dummy data
const context = {
  allOrganizations: [
    {
      name: 'Organization 1',
      topic: {
        searchTerms: ['term1', 'term2'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Organization 2',
      topic: {
        searchTerms: ['term5', 'term6'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Organization 3',
      topic: {
        searchTerms: ['term7', 'term8'],
      },
    },
  ],
};

// filter organizations
const filteredOrganizations = context.allOrganizations.filter((organization) =>
  (
    organization.topic.searchTerms
      // remove whitespace and convert to lowercase
      .map((term) => term.trim().toLowerCase())
      // join terms into a single string
      .join(' ') +
    // add organization name
    ' ' +
    organization.name
  )
    .toLowerCase()

    // check if search text is included in the string
    .includes(searchText.trim().toLowerCase())
);

console.log(filteredOrganizations);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).